# Determine when a table cell has begun dragging (moving) in a possible move operation

Tags: uitableview, ios5

I've got a re-orderable table view (`UITableView` instance). Although I've implemented the `UITableViewDataSource` method:

```
tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:
```

This only fires on drop of the moved table cell.

I want a callback that tells me that a cell has just been gripped by it's reordering control and is about to take flight. I didn't catch this in the API.

**Purpose:** As soon as a move operation is even being flirted with, I'd like to remove other decorations on my main view that are no longer valid. Ideally, I'm looking for something like a call back (I can wish right!) that read like this:

```
tableView:didBeginPossibleMoveOfRowAtIndexPath:
```

Neither UITableViewDataSource nor UITableViewDelegate protocols give me hooks for this. Or did I miss something?

Comment: Ideally we'd have `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` and `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`

Answer (score -2):

```
 - (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
 - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
 - (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
```

use this now when you will start to scroll the tableview then

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

will start to work.

when you are scrolling then

```
 - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

will call.

At the end of your scrolling this method will start to work,

```
 - (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
```

I hope you have understood.May be it will help you.

Thanks

Comment: Emon: I'm not looking for callbacks about the table view scrolling. I'm looking for a callback that an individual table *cell* has bee lifted for reordering.